# Setting up our own private docker hub

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, boot2docker, docker-registry

I want to set up my own private docker hub from where I can pull docker images on docker clients.

Taking this [link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2464012&seqNum=2) as reference, I executed following commands on one machine:

```
docker pull registry
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name localregistry registry
docker ps
docker pull alpine
docker tag alpine:latest localhost:5000/alpine:latest
docker push localhost:5000/alpine:latest
```

I want to pull this image on some other machine which is reachable to/from this machine.

```
$ docker pull <ip_of_machine>:5000/alpine
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://<ip_of_machine>:5000/v1/_ping: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

Is it possible to pull docker image from one machine which acts as a docker hub to another machine which is reachable?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

Comment: From the link given, I added DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry myregistrydomain.com:5000", saved it and restarted docker but still getting this error: $ docker pull 10.5.12.32:5000/alpine
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://<ip>:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp <ip>:5000: getsockopt: connection refused

Comment: A "connection refused" message generally means either (a) the thing to which you are trying to connect is not actually listening where you think it is, or (b) your firewall is set up to `REJECT` the connection and needs to be modified.

Comment: I have tried with the exact hostname-domain.com keeping in /etc/default/docker, same is pinging but while docker pull, it gives error.

Comment: root@dev:/docker-images/ind-dockerfiles# docker push localhost:5000/alpine:latest
The push refers to a repository [localhost:5000/alpine]
Put http://localhost:5000/v1/repositories/alpine/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: getsockopt: connection refused
root@dev:/docker-images/ind-dockerfiles# curl http://localhost:5000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused

Comment: I see from the tags are you using boot2docker? I mean Docker Toolbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding below line in docker client machine's /etc/sysconfig/docker file resolved the issue:

```
INSECURE_REGISTRY='--insecure-registry <ip>:5000'
```

Comment: if you have the Docker Desktop, you can go to Preferences... > Docker Engine and set `{"insecure-registries": ["<ip>:5000"]}` (skip brackets if you already have ones)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by the tags you are using boot2docker or DockerToolbox:

1. You must open VirtualBox Manager
2. Select the default machine
3. Network
4. NAT
5. Port forwarding
6. Add an entry for the 5000 port

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to resolve the issue by putting INSECURE_REGISTRY='--insecure-registry 10.5.12.32:5000' line in /etc/sysconfig/docker.

Comment: In my local system, it only works in the same machine. If I create registry in one machine, and try to connect it in another machine.It desnt work. I am using the latest 18.01 DockerToolbox under  Windows 10, and the registry port 5000 is exposed, and docker machine ip is mapped to localhost, and add `"InsecureRegistry": [
                "localhost:5000",
                "127.0.0.1:5000"
            ]`  to another machine, when I try to exe `docker push`, and got failure. `getsockopt: connection refused`